# Close the page after certain interval [Puppeteer]

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have used puppeteer for one of my projects to open webpages in headless chrome, do some actions and then close the page. These actions, however, are user dependent. I want to attach a lifetime to the page, where it closes automatically after, say 30 minutes, of opening irrespective of whether any action is performed or not.

I have tried `setTimeout()` functionality of Node JS but it didn't work (or I just couldn't figure how to make it work).
I have tried the following:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL: browser_url});
const page = await browser.newPage();
// timer starts ticking here upon creation of new page (maybe in a subroutine and not block the main thread)

/**
 ..
 Do something
 ..
*/

// timer ends and closePage() is triggered.

const closePage = (page) => {
    if (!page.isClosed()) {
        page.close();
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:
`Error: Protocol error: Connection closed. Most likely the page has been closed.`

Answer (score 2):

Your provided code should work as excepted. Are you sure the page is still opened after the timeout and it is indeed the same page?

You can try this wrapper for opening pages and closing them correctly.

```js
// since it is async it won't block the eventloop. 
// using `await` will allow other functions to execute.
async function openNewPage(browser, timeoutMs) {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    setTimeout(async () => {
        // you want to use try/catch for omitting unhandled promise rejections.
        try {
            if(!page.isClosed()) {
                await page.close()
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.error('unexpected error occured when closing page.', err)
        }
       
    }, timeoutMs)
}

// use it like so.
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL: browser_url});

const min30Ms = 30 * 60 * 1000
const page = await openNewPage(browser, min30Ms);
// ...
```

The above only closes the `Tabs` in your browser. For closing the puppeteer instance you would have to call `browser.close()` which could may be what you want?

Comment: I have tried your solution and it gives me the same error which I was getting before. Have added the error log now in the post, sorry missed it earlier. Also, I don't want to close the browser. I just don't want the idle tabs to be opened in the browser so as to minimise the number of opened pages (for optimal performance).

Comment: That error occurs if you are doing some work on your page and certainly call `page.close()`. That what happens to your main script if you close the page within the run, with the above code ofc. .

Comment: The error trace shows that it is thrown on the same line where we are calling `page.close()`. This gives me a feeling that either it is trying to close an already closed page or not able to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

`page.close` returns a promise so you need to define `closePage` as an async function and use `await page.close()`. I believe @silvan's answer should address the issue, just make sure to replace if condition

```
if(page.isClosed())
```

with

```
if(!page.isClosed())
```